# HEAP corruption when making shared library calls using Linux RHL 6.2

Tags: memory, corruption

I have ported code from Solaris/Sparc/x86 using Sun compilers to Red Hat Linux 6.2 using GCC 4.4.6 and I am having problems with the code reporting memory corruption under valgrind and core dumping.

The same source runs without error on Solaris, both Sparc and x86.

The area where the error occurs is in a shared library I am calling to retrieve system configuration.

The memory it is complaining about are local stack variables in the shared library.  Valgrind is not helping me locate the actual area where the failure is occurring.

The DBGMEM memory debugger with "-d check -b -p 1" options does not detect any memory that I can see in the report and the program exits normally.

The valgrind memory debugger with "-v --leak-check=yes --read-var-info=yes" options is failing, reporting invalid writes.

From valgrind log:

```
==22043== Invalid write of size 8
==22043==    at 0x51DF74D: setLockingMode (db_support_funcs.c:258)
==22043==    by 0x40BF4E: GetAmaHdrParameters (AmaFileWriter.c:3707)
==22043==    by 0x40490E: MakeAMADNSFile (AmaFileWriter.c:899)
==22043==    by 0x403109: main (MakeAmaFile.c:775)
==22043==  Address 0x7fefebea8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22043== 
==22043== Invalid write of size 8
==22043==    at 0x51DF348: logconfig (db_support_funcs.c:228)
==22043==    by 0x51DF790: setLockingMode (db_support_funcs.c:257)
==22043==    by 0x40BF4E: GetAmaHdrParameters (AmaFileWriter.c:3707)
==22043==    by 0x40490E: MakeAMADNSFile (AmaFileWriter.c:899)
==22043==    by 0x403109: main (MakeAmaFile.c:775)
==22043==  Address 0x7fefebd68 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22043== 
==22043== Invalid write of size 8
==22043==    at 0x51DF36A: logconfig (db_support_funcs.c:176)
==22043==    by 0x51DF790: setLockingMode (db_support_funcs.c:257)
==22043==    by 0x40BF4E: GetAmaHdrParameters (AmaFileWriter.c:3707)
==22043==    by 0x40490E: MakeAMADNSFile (AmaFileWriter.c:899)
==22043==    by 0x403109: main (MakeAmaFile.c:775)
==22043==  Address 0x7fefebcc8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22043== 
==22043== Invalid write of size 8
==22043==    at 0x51DF396: logconfig (db_support_funcs.c:177)
==22043==    by 0x51DF790: setLockingMode (db_support_funcs.c:257)
==22043==    by 0x40BF4E: GetAmaHdrParameters (AmaFileWriter.c:3707)
==22043==    by 0x40490E: MakeAMADNSFile (AmaFileWriter.c:899)
==22043==    by 0x403109: main (MakeAmaFile.c:775)
==22043==  Address 0x7fefeacb8 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22043== 
==22043== 
==22043== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV): dumping core
==22043==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x7FEFEACB8
==22043==    at 0x51DF396: logconfig (db_support_funcs.c:177)
==22043==    by 0x51DF790: setLockingMode (db_support_funcs.c:257)
==22043==    by 0x40BF4E: GetAmaHdrParameters (AmaFileWriter.c:3707)
==22043==    by 0x40490E: MakeAMADNSFile (AmaFileWriter.c:899)
==22043==    by 0x403109: main (MakeAmaFile.c:775)
==22043==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22043==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22043==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22043==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22043==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
```

The function being call source in db_support_funcs.c is:

```
-- line 255 -- void setLockingMode( short locking )
-- line 256 -- {
-- line 257 --    logconfig(0, LOG_DEBUG1, "DEBUG1:[%s:%d]:setLockingMode(locking=%d), currently %d", __FILE__,__LINE__, locking, disable_lock);
-- line 258 --    disable_lock = locking;
-- line 259 -- }

-- line 168 -- void logconfig( int errnoflag, int level, const char *fmt, ... )
-- line 169 -- {
-- line 170 --    va_list     ap;
-- line 171 --    int         errno_save = errno; /* Value caller might want printed */
-- line 172 --    long        n;
-- line 173 --    time_t      curr_time;
-- line 174 --    struct tm   *curr_tm,
-- line 175 --                *stat_tm;
-- line 176 --    struct stat stat_buff;
-- line 177 --    char        buff[BIG_BUFFER_LEN];
-- line 178 --    static char pid_str[MAX_PATH_LEN];
-- line 179 --    static int  first_time = 1;
```

The code was compiled with the following switch options:
Shared Lib:
     -D_LINUX_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DDEBUG_ENABLED -Wall -Wwrite-strings -DDEBUG -DTHREAD_SAFE -g -fstack-check -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DNOPROTX -pthread -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN=1234 -D_LITTLEENDIAN -DL_ENDIAN -fPIC -DTHREAD_SAFE -shared -fPIC

App:
      -D_LINUX_SOURCE -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -DDEBUG_ENABLED -Wall -Wwrite-strings -DDEBUG -g -fstack-check -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-align -DNOPROTX -pthread -g -D__LITTLE_ENDIAN=1234 -D_LITTLEENDIAN -DL_ENDIAN -fPIC

I am using gcc version 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3) (GCC)

Answer (score 0):

Since the errors are being reported mostly for the local variables of the log function, I infer that your program is overrunning the thread's stack. The bottom of the report hints to this:

```
==22043==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==22043==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==22043==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==22043==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==22043==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 10485760.
```

`valgrind` is using 10MB for the main thread stack. Compare this stack size to the expected memory used on the stack by each function in the call chain in the `valgrind` error report.

Comment: I have tried 4x the stack size as a quick check and no difference in outcome.

Comment: ==29969==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==29969==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==29969==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==29969==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==29969==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 41943040.

Comment: How big is BIG_BUFFER_LEN? You didn't give me the expected size of your stack at the moment of the crash.